# reference for a special modular decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

For modular decomposition.

X is a module if all members of X have the same set of neighbors among vertices not in X.

I need a special modular decomposition.

X is my module if all members of X have the same set of neighbors among vertices not in X, and X is a clique.

I think this should have been studied already, I would like to avoid redefining it and use some non-standard name, can someone give me some reference?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed this concept exists. Two vertices $u,v$ that have the same neighbors are often called twins. They are called true twins if they are also connected, and false twins otherwise. In your definition, all vertices of $X$ are true twins.

It looks like there are several other names in the literature for these concepts. See e.g. this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142467/does-the-notion-of-graphs-with-vertex-multiplicity-exist). In FPT algorithms we sometimes call the number of twin classes into which a graph can be partitioned the neighborhood diversity of the graph, see e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00453-011-9554-x?LI=true) (warning: self-citation!), and [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-28050-4_21) for the related notion of twin-cover.

Comment: this MO question, what does MO mean?

Comment: @Ginger Math Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Clique modules has been re-discovered many times. In this paper, they are called "critical cliques" (and many other bioinformatics papers and algorithmic graph theory papers)

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~ghlin/src/Paper/5root_KKL08.pdf

In this 2005 paper by Hsu: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-56402-0_31  they are called "Type I modules" . This paper of Hsu cites this terminology back to the 1991 paper by Hsu and Ma on obtaining a modular decomposition of chordal graphs (predating the first linear-time modular decomposition algorithm). I think the Hsu+Ma paper is the earliest reference I've seen that assigns any special name to clique modules.